# I dont know what is wrong ? MATLAB error in 'int'

Tags: integration, matlab

I am new to MATLAB.
I tried to use this command but it gives an error.

Can you please point out  what is wrong.?

```
int(int(int((4*x),x,0,1),y,0,1),z,0,1)
error: Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'
```

Thank You very much

Anupam

Comment: Have you initialised `x`, `y` or `z` before this line?

Comment: This Q&A site is for mathematics and questions about mathematics. For questions about programming or programming languages, you should consider asking elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syms x y z

int(int(int((4*x),x,0,1),y,0,1),z,0,1)